Dealing with wrong currency calculation in Javascript
I have an app that deals with basic currency calculation in node.js and react.js. We are dealing with the usual operations of multiplication, addition, subtraction and division. I have noticed that when dealing with longer operations, I tend to lose maybe 4 cents which usually happen when calculation results to decimal numbers during the operation.
Take a look at this code:
 const currencyCalculation = (amount, actionValue, operationSign)=>{

  const expression = /[^0-9 .\-]/g;

  const amountToString = amount?.toString();
  const filteredNum = amountToString.replace(expression, "");
  const m = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, {
  style: "currency",

  currency: "USD",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
 }).format(Number(filteredNum) operationSign actionValue);

 const finalResult = m?.replace(expression, "");

 return finalResult;

 };

The operationSign value can be + | - | * 
Look at this example, we have a system where users pay deposit before checking out and the rest of the balance is spread out across different dates to be paid in installments.
Now, let say we have a total amount like this $8975.4;  and our deposit sum is $398;
First, I subtracted the 398 from the total sum which is 8975.4. The answer would be 8577.4 which is correct. The user has 19 months to pay the rest of the balance which means I would divide the balance by 19 to get the amount they would pay per month.
So, we have 8577.4/ 19. All of these operations happen with the above currencyCalculation function. The division returned to 451.44 per month for 19 months.
I wanted to cross check if adding each months due sum all together plus the deposit sum would give me the exact total sum of the order and I discovered that I would be losing 4 cents across the process.
So, 451.44 * 19 gave me 8577.36 and adding the 398 deposit to it returned 8975.36 instead of 8975.4 which is basically $8975.40. How do I deal with issues like this? Is it possible to always get the accurate amount back during installment payment like this? I would prefer to have surplus than shorting values.
Please help me with proper steps to take.

Most floating-point numeric systems in modern computers are based on base-2 exponents and fractions, and so they don't work well with base-10 "money math" for exactly the reasons you have discovered. That's why languages like Java and C# etc have decimal math packages that are explicitly designed to do money math properly and predictably.

Does it mean there is no work around for me? The entire application was built with javascript. I read somewhere about rounding up the decimal digits. I don't know how that works. I have not seen any information that can help.

The points brought up by @Pointy (pun intended) are absolutely valid. I would recommend to add Dinero.js to your application and handle monetary calculations with it. It's a library explicitely designed for this use case: https://github.com/dinerojs/dinero.js

Alternatively check out https://github.com/scurker/currency.js/

Basically, new Intl.NumberFormat was not designed to handle currency operations, right? I mean like calculations and all that. It is just for formatting?

The problem in your case is that 8577.4 / 19 === 451.442105263 so you are losing $0.002... for every payment (because of rounding to two digits). The only proper way to deal with this is, to be aware of such a situation when calculating your payments and add the missing $0.004 to one of the payments ... In other situations you may result in a payment of for instance $123.45678 which will give you $123.46 for each single payment, ie the sum will be too much. Same here, you have to substract the overpaid few cents from one of the payments.

That is too much work to handle because is there a way I can detect these scenarios and handle them easily? Or is going the way of a package the best for me?

doing let rate = +(totalpayment / ratecount).toFixed(2); let diff = +(totalpayment - ratecount * rate).toFixed(2); let finalrate = rate + diff  is too much work?

oh, thanks! I didn't know that was the way. I have resolve it though. Since My total order sum will always be correct as there is no traces of float number in it. I have decided to simply check if the payment plans when added together in addition to deposit sum will equal to the order total sum, if it is less, how much is needed to complete it, add that amount to the last payment plan, if it is more, subtract that difference from the last payment plan.
